# how would i go about creating variable menu links

Tags: 7, routes

I would like to display different menu links on each page depending on the content and relevance of each page. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context)

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.

Comment: Thank you!
I could also use the same module to for example display recently created pages, is that correct? @NickilM

Comment: @kine456, sure you can..